# How do I make my .net, WPF, WinForms, etc applications work on an ARM powered Windows 8 System?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, arm, windows-8

There are clearly lot of limitations to what will run on the new ARM based Windows 8 systems.

However given the .net is meant to be CPU independent, I was hoping that most .net based desktop apps will work on an ARM powered Windows 8 system, with little or no work form the developer.

Was my hope misplaced?

Answer (score 2):

In the //build/ keynote, Steven Sinofsky said that Metro style apps will work.  C# and JavaScript will run without any changes.  C++ will work with recompilation.  Microsoft has not made a statement about desktop apps and Arm.

Answer (score 2):

Existing windows forms or wpf apps won't work on an ARM-powered Windows 8 system (called Windows RT).  They won't work even with a recompile.  Windows RT uses a new, different API.

Also, there is no x86 emulator in Windows RT.

Answer (score 1):

This link says use WinRT.

Excerpt:

"OK, so if you want to build native apps for Windows 8 that will run on both x86 and ARM hardware, what are you supposed to do? The answer is "".

http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/sep/14/windows-8-metro-developer-viewpoint

Also, read this:

http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/09/build-2011-what-is-winrt-and-i.php

Comment: Does that mean that WPF applications won't run on ARM Win8?

Comment: XAML will. I dont know about WPF. Also, see this link:http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/A-first-encounter-with-Windows8-Development-%28C-XAML-JavaScript%29.aspx

Comment: I was not talking about Metro at all, I'm just want to know if purely managed WPF apps will run on ARM without recompilation.

Comment: Since when have 3rd hand info sources like the guardian been trust worthly on this sort of thing?